# Re-open the Game of Thrones missing characters question (105371)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

The question [Which Game of Thrones book characters are missing from the HBO series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/105371/21267) was closed as **too-broad**, and rightfully so.

It has since been edited, and in my opinion is not too broad any more. It in fact has an excellent answer.

**Should this question be re-opened?**

Comment: I already voted to reopen. Seems we're the only two to have done so.

Comment: I love how you've put the question ID number in the title, as if someone will see this title and think "Ahhh, question 105371, I remember it well. Yes, I believe question 105371's time has come"

Comment: Might it be worth doing a week-by-week format for these show/books differences questions? Or is that too reddit-y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The question has been re-opened by the community.

For details, see the question's [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/105371/revisions).